# React State for an interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a chart that has a time range component attached to it. The time range works but I want the currently selected interval to be blue. I tried doing this with a ternary operator but it just makes them all blue.

here is the code for the time range.

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../styles.scss'
import { useState } from 'react'

const TimeRange = ({ intervals, onChange, vertical }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(intervals)

  return (
    <div
      className="TimeRange-container"
      style={{
        justifyContent: vertical && 'center',
      }}
    >
      {!vertical && <div className="TimeRange-timeframe">Time Frame: </div>}

      <div
        className="TimeRange-range-container"
        style={{
          flexDirection: vertical && 'column',
        }}
      >
        {intervals.map(interval => {
          return (
            <div
              className="interval-container"
              onClick={() => onChange(interval)}
            >
              <div
                className="interval-continer-select"
                style={{
                  color:
                    selected.label === selected.current &&
                    'var(--primary-color',
                }}
              >
                {interval.label}
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TimeRange
```

Here is an example of how the 'intervals' are set up.

```
import moment from 'moment'

export const Intervals = [
  {
    label: '7d',
    from: moment().subtract(4, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 7,
  },
  {
    label: '1m',
    from: moment().subtract(5, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 30,
  },
  {
    label: '3m',
    from: moment().subtract(6, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 90,
  },
  {
    label: '6m',
    from: moment().subtract(8, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 182,
  },
  {
    label: '1Y',
    from: moment().subtract(8, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 365,
  },
  {
    label: '2Y',
    from: moment().subtract(8, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 730,
  },
  {
    label: '3Y',
    from: moment().subtract(8, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: 1095,
  },
  {
    label: 'All',
    from: moment().subtract(100, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    to: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    limit: -1,
  },
]
```

How do I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected label in state, not the whole array.

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
```

Then, when rendering the intervals:

```
<div
  className="interval-container"
  onClick={() => setSelected(interval.label)}>
  <div
    className="interval-continer-select"
    style={{
      color:
        selected === interval.label &&
        'var(--primary-color)',
    }}
  >
    {interval.label}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Just crashes the page. Maybe I'm using the wrong things here "selected.label === selected.current" ?

Comment: @LearningBeNice Sorry, I forgot to change that line. It should be `selected === interval.label`

Comment: Thansk. I got it to work but i also had to add a  onClick={() => setSelected(interval)}

Comment: @LearningBeNice Did using `onClick={() => setSelected(interval.label)}` (shown in my answer) not work? It'd be better to store just the label of the selected item, not the whole object.